# Mapping countries to latitude and longitude information

Tags: python, algorithm, latitude-longitude

I have a lot of latitude and longitude information that belong to different countries. How do I map each of these lat-long to the country it belongs to in an efficient manner?

I came across googleapis, but that would be very inefficient and time consuming if I had to query this api for every lat-long pair that I have. I thought of grouping all the lat-long pairs that are closer and then figure out a way to find the country that each of these groups belongs to.

Could you please point me to the right algorithms that I could use for this purpose? Or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: This question is about finding belonging to polygons. You'd need polygons with property country to start with I guess. Tons of questions about the first thing I mentioned though

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11331/iso-country-code-for-lon-lat-0-5degx0-5deg-cells

Comment: I would first check against each country bounding box and in case you have multiple matches go for reverse geocoding.
For a visual look at (axis aligned) bounding boxes, see https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/bounds/

Answer (score 2):

```
import reverse_geocode

coordinates = (-37.81, 144.96), (31.76, 35.21)

reverse_geocode.search(coordinates)
```

Can find the locations offline like this using the `python` `reverse_geocode` library